# Create Noisy Font animation

Tags: p5.js, noise

So I have to create a Noisy Font which looks like the output below.

[Desired Output](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/imageAssetProxy.v1/t-b8fbOATn2m_H2zgD59Bg_a7453f2b906e8687e8b8f4780a0ee529_noisyFont.gif?expiry=1606521600000&hmac=ouG8oxT5nqZbJ3U07i6wdU0EG3GAiysdak892QI84EE)

My Noisy Font has to follow these instructions:

Within the for loop, calculate a value nX that is generated from the noise() function. Pass into the noise() function the frameCount correctly scaled. Map that to a value between -amt and amt where amt is equal to 20.

Add that value returned from map() to the coordinate of each point. Do the same for nY. If you’ve done things right the entire word should move diagonally.

Make nX be different for each point by adding the point´s x and y coordinate to the frameCount and passing that to noise instead. Do the same for nY. If you’ve done things right each point now should move independently for the others, but they are still each moving diagonally.

Add a number (any number) to the parameters you pass to nY. This way we are decoupling the nX and nY values from each other as nY reads from a different point in the noise graph.

Play with amt. Set it to be dependent on mouseX and have it range from 0 to 80.

However, [my output](https://im6.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-6-46074ac82536.gif) does not match the desired output. Here's my code below:

```
var points;
var font;
function preload() {
  font = loadFont('assets/Calistoga-Regular.ttf');
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 400);
  fill(255, 104, 204, 150);
    noStroke();

  points = font.textToPoints('c o d e', 50, 300, 300, {
    sampleFactor: .3,
    simplifyThreshold: 0
  });
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function draw() {
    fill(0,5);
    rect(0,0,width,height);

    for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        fill(255, 104, 204, 150);
        var point = points[i];
        var pX = frameCount+point.x;
        var pY = frameCount+point.y+5;
        var nX = noise(pX);
        var nY = noise(pY);
        var amt = map(mouseX, 0, 20, 0, 80);
        var mX = map(nX,0,pX,-amt,amt);
        var mY = map(nY,0,pY,-amt,amt);
        var x = point.x + random(-mX, mX);
        var y = point.y + random(-mY, mY);
        ellipse(x,y,10,10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your problem is that the font is too noisy?
In that case, the problem is that you are mapping `amt` to too high a value. This is because you tell it that the range is `0` to `20`, but the actual range is `0` to `width`. To fix that, replace this:

```
var amt = map(mouseX, 0, 20, 0, 80)
```

with this:

```
var amt = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 80);
```

Edit: Here are a couple of problems  in your code:

In the instructions, it says: *"Pass into the noise() function the frameCount **correctly scaled**"*. In your code, you don't scale the framecount (multiply it by a small number, for example `0.1`).

*"Make nX be different for each point by adding the point´s x and y coordinate"*. In your code, you are only adding `point.x` to the `framecount` for `pX` and only adding point.y for `pY`.

Also, you are mapping `nx` from `0` to `pX`, when it only goes from `0` to `1` (that is always the case with the `noise()` function).

The last problem is that you are using the `random()` function. If you are using the `random()` function, the values will never change smoothly and the trails will not connect. Here is the fixed code:

```
var point = points[i];
var pX = (frameCount * 0.1) + point.x + point.y;
var pY = pX + 5;
var nX = noise(pX);
var nY = noise(pY);
var amt = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 80);
var mX = map(nX,0,1,-amt,amt);
var mY = map(nY,0,1,-amt,amt);
var x = point.x + mX;
var y = point.y + mY;
```

If you want to change how smooth the trails are, you can change to `0.1`

Comment: Ok, I did that but it still doesn't look like the desired output. I think it has to do with the trail of the circles. There's another instruction to map the trail of the circles to mouseY but I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: It is hard to help you without actually knowing what your desired result is. I am unsure of what is meant by "map the trail of the circles to mouseY". The trail should be entirely dependent of how the circles move. Is that all the given information?

Comment: [desired result](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/imageAssetProxy.v1/t-b8fbOATn2m_H2zgD59Bg_a7453f2b906e8687e8b8f4780a0ee529_noisyFont.gif?expiry=1606521600000&hmac=ouG8oxT5nqZbJ3U07i6wdU0EG3GAiysdak892QI84EE) It says I should connect the trail of the particles to mouseY by playing with the fill function.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I have updated the answer and this should fix most, if not all, of your problems

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks like the desired output now. I just have one more part that I don't quite understand. "Play with the trail the particles leave by modifying the fill of the rect in the draw function. Connect it with mouseY". Does this mean like this: fill(0, mouseY) or something like that?

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes, I believe that is what is meant. You can use the map() function to map mouseY between 0 and 255 and use that as the alpha value (transparency) of the background. That way, you can change how long the trails stay there